# Avoid re-downloading files with Termux in its own downloads folder

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, file-management, terminal, termux

I have some files for which I don't have any app to open them with, but whenever I try to open them, instead of the "try looking in the Play Store for an app to open your file" dialog, I get this from Termux:

[image: Termux text dialog to rename and save the file in the folder home/downloads/ with the options "Open Directory", "Cancel" and "Edit"]

And I don't want to copy the file into a second "downloads" folder, because I already have it in `~/storage/shared/Download`

Comment: Go to Termux App Info screen and clear defaults. But if you don't have any other app installed which can handle `.xlsx` files, Android will automatically pick Termux because it can handle many types of files. // There is a [solution](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/commit/af6ac30bb1b062ccca5813e65380c8cafe20eaa3) in the latest Termux release. Add `disable-file-share-receiver=true` and `disable-file-view-receiver=true` entry to `termux.properties` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that doesn't work:

1. Go to your homescreen
2. Press and hold the termux icon
3. There would be an icon which looks like an 'i'. Tap on it
4. Scroll down and clear defaults

But you'll mostly end up seeing no such options and even if there exists one, it wont be helpful in this case.

I can confirm since I reproduced your issue on my device using the stock Android file manager.

The only possible fix is installing an application that can open such extensions, in your case for xlsx files, the official Microsoft Excel android app or Xodo docs would do the trick.